# javascript jquery slide out tab

Tags: jquery, css, flash

jquery slide out tab is going over my flash

http://isomham.com/TEST/index2.html

any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: not getting problem on chrome.  Could you revise your question to include steps to reproduce and browser it shows up in?

Comment: Also not getting it in Safari or Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Set the wmode parameter of the flash to "transparent"

See this http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html

Change your code like so:

```
AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','width','218','height','386','src','working','quality','high','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','working', 
'wmode','transparent'  ); //<--- add this!
```